# Tomcat 404 not found error when run from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat6

Spring web.xml

```
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>E-Attendance</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class> 
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
    </servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>E-Attendance</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>E-Attendance</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/E-Attendance-servlet.xml</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Then I run Tomcat from Eclipse under Server tab.
But I get ***http-status-404 (The requested resource is not available.)*** error when I go to the link `http://localhost:8080/E-Attendance/login.htm`

Is there something wrong with set up? 
I don't have any error in tomcat logs too.
My project is in workspace folder under Eclipse. 
Appreciate all of your help.

```
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 334 ms
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'E-Attendance'
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.catalina.Registry', 'org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry@5ed853')
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.catalina.MBeanServer', 'com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@cc5436')
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory extraprj
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory spring-security-integration.war
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/14  config=null
Apr 29, 2014 8:05:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3318 ms
```

Comment: There could be problem in tomcat start up. Are you seeing something like "error while startup".

Comment: You have to provide more details ;)

Comment: Hi Krishna, There is no error while startup... I have added the log in the post in case you want to look at. And i see the Tom cat welcome page when I go to http:localhost:8080

Comment: the first url pattern is enough for redirecting every request to dispatcher servlet. You really don't need *.htm

Comment: where is your controller btw?

Comment: It is surely set up problem. With the details you have provided, not easy to figure out what is wrong. In the tomcat log I am not seeing anything as loading the servlet E-Attendence. I am doubting whether the application itself not loaded.